How to pass Authorization header from Next.js app to backend service?
I am creating a Next.js web app that connects to an existing backend service to retrieve data.  The backend service contains endpoints that require authentication (OAuth2 / Authorization header).  There is a flow in which I could do this using the Next.js backend as a proxy (browser -> Next.js backend -> existing backend service).  In this scenario, the backend has the user's auth token and adds it to the request to the backend service.
But this seems redundant.  I want to call my backend service directly from the frontend using something like Axios in the frontend.  Is this possible?  How would I get the user's auth token in order to make this call to my backend service?

You can add the JWT to server side's response with the Set-Cookie header, so the brower will store it in the cookies. The client side can read it from there and add it to the axios header: Authorization: Bearer [jwt]. If you're working with next-auth as your tag suggests, you can use the Session Provider to receive the JWT, and add it to you request in the same manner.

Note that the creation of the JWT must not be implemented purely at the client side, b/c the authorization code flow requires a client secret which must not be known by the user.
